# Removing part of a string javascript not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to remove the second part of this string (the second block)

```
<resourceDescriptor name="report_mongodb_new_basic" wsType="reportUnit"  uriString="/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic" isNew="false">
<label><![CDATA[report mongodb new basic]]></label>
<description><![CDATA[test 3]]></description>
<creationDate>1330693884348</creationDate>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
    <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports.domain.ReportUnit]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
    <value><![CDATA[/reports/samples]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
    <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_ALWAYS_PROPMT_CONTROLS">
    <value><![CDATA[false]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_CONTROLS_LAYOUT">
    <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_REPORT_RENDERING_VIEW">
    <value><![CDATA[]]></value>
</resourceProperty>
<resourceDescriptor wsType="datasource" isNew="false">
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_REFERENCE_URI">
        <value><![CDATA[/datasources/MongoDB]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_IS_REFERENCE">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
```

```
<resourceDescriptor name="report_mongodb_new_basic_" wsType="jrxml" uriString="/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic_files/report_mongodb_new_basic_" isNew="false">
    <label><![CDATA[report mongodb new basic]]></label>
    <creationDate>1330693884348</creationDate>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
        <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.FileResource]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
        <value><![CDATA[/reports/samples/report_mongodb_new_basic_files]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
        <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_IS_REFERENCE">
        <value><![CDATA[false]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_HAS_DATA">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_ATTACHMENT_ID">
        <value><![CDATA[attachment]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
    <resourceProperty name="PROP_RU_IS_MAIN_REPORT">
        <value><![CDATA[true]]></value>
    </resourceProperty>
</resourceDescriptor>
```

I want only the first block 
( `From : <resourceDescriptor to </resourceDescriptor>` 
I am currently doing this but it's not working :

```
var sbody = a.body; //sbody is a String
sbody.split("</resourceDescriptor>").pop();
console.log(sbody);
```

The result change nothing (COnsole.log is nodejs it's a print)
OR

```
sbody.substring(sbody.indexOf("<resourceDescriptor>") + 1, sbody.indexOf("</resourceDescriptor>"));
console.log(sbody);
```

The result change also nothing, why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop` returns the popped value it does not alter the object/array
 its called against;

```
var result = sbody.split("</resourceDescriptor>").pop();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: THanks ! , FYI actually `pop` doesn't work but substring yes  I have the first block but not the last part of it (</resourceDescriptor>
)

Comment: This is working (but ugly) : `var nbody =sbody.substring(sbody.indexOf("<resourceDescriptor>") + 1, sbody.indexOf("</resourceDescriptor>")+21);`

Answer (score 1):

This will gives you string buffer except end resourceDescriptor

```
sbody.split("</resourceDescriptor>")[0];
console.log(sbody);
```

Comment: actually you need a new var like Alex K said, your method work but I need the "</resourceDescriptor>" at the end

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is: 
add the above XML inside the hidden div in your DOM, then you can access it using getElementByTagName or jQuery methods.